# Perl Script not returning any value when called from batch?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I'm calling a perl script from batch and giving an appropriate parameter, it's suppose to return either 1, 2,3 or 4.  But its not. I checked the output of Perl from the command line, and they are outputting the correct result, I think its in the batch syntax

#### Batch:

```
@echo off 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /F "delims=*" %%I IN ('Perl C:/ExecutionSDKTest_10.2.2/TestProp1noRefCheck.pl 844') DO     set lineCase=%%I  
echo line case is !lineCase!
```

#### Perl:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
sub main1;

my $arg1 =shift;
main1($arg1);
exit;
sub main1
{
            #Returns 1,2,3 Depending on testNum passed
            my @gp1= (829,845,851,859,864,867);
            my @gp2= (861,863,865);
            # my @gp4= (826-828,830-839,843-844,847-850,852-854,860-862,883);
    # my @gp3= (877-882,884);
            my $val1=1;
            my $val2=2;
            my $val3=3;
            my $val4=4;

            if((grep /^$arg1$/,@gp1) || ($arg1 >=822 && $arg1<=824))
            {     
                            # print "$val1\n";
                            return $val1;

            } elsif ((grep /^$arg1$/,@gp2) || ($arg1>=855 && $arg1<=858))
            {
            #print "$val2\n";
                            return $val2;
            } elsif (($arg1==884) || ($arg1>=877 && $arg1<=882))
            {
            #print "$val3\n";
                            return $val3;
            } else
            {
                #print "$val4\n";
                            return $val4;

            }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a `test.cmd` like this:

```
@echo off 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%I in (%*) do (
   call perlfake %%I
   set lineCase=!ERRORLEVEL!
   echo line case [for %%I] is !lineCase!
)
```

Then created `perlfake.cmd` in the same directory:

```
@echo off 
set /a returnvalue="%1 %% 4 + 1"
REM echo (%1 mod 4) + 1 = %returnvalue%
exit /b %returnvalue%
```

Then call `test 1 2 3 4 844 35`.

Results:

```
line case [for 1] is 2
line case [for 2] is 3
line case [for 3] is 4
line case [for 4] is 1
line case [for 844] is 1
line case [for 35] is 4
```

The logic for determining your actual return values is different to your perl code, but as you can see, this is just fake code.

So check this against your perl code, by changing the call to be:

```
REM call perlfake %%I
call Perl C:/ExecutionSDKTest_10.2.2/TestProp1noRefCheck.pl %%I
```

About your Perl script, I can see that you are throwing away your return value from main1, when you do this:

```
main1($arg1);
exit;
```

You want something like:

```
my $result = main1($arg1);
exit $result;
```

Exiting from Perl like this will set the errorlevel.

*Edit:*

I've now downloaded ActiveState's Perl 5.14.2, and changed my batch to call your perl script, with my changes to return $result. It all works now, eg:
`test.cmd 844 861`

Returns:

```
line case [for 844] is 4
line case [for 861] is 2
```